# How can I change first sheet name in SimpleXLSXGen?

Tags: php, excel, xlsx

I wanted to export and save data from my page to Excel using PHP and I found excellent source https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen

I can make multiple sheets using this code

```
        $xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $myarray);
        $xlsx->addSheet( $myarray, 'My name for sheet 2' );
        $xlsx->addSheet( $myarray, 'My name for sheet 3' );
        $xlsx->saveAs($filename.'.xlsx');
```

But I can't figure out, how can I name my first sheet? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `$xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen(); $xlsx->addSheet( $myarray, 'My name for sheet 1' ); …`?

Comment: Oh... Okay, it showed me an error again, but now I know, where the problem was. Solution like in your comment, just the word "new" was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look at source code and find

```
fromArray( array $rows, $sheetName = null )
```

comment out `null` and pass in new sheetname.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little bit late, but I hope it helps others with same question...

use

```
$xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $myarray, 'name of first sheet');
```

instead

```
$xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $myarray);
```